# Can't run yeoman application with grunt, cdnify.js

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, bower

I've project to join so I cloned repo from git. I have installed `npm install` and then `bower install`, but when I try to run the app with `grunt serve` command, console returns this:

```
Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'chalk'

Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/tomek/dev/mobilas/app/bower.json' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The thing is, I shouldn't really change neither Gruntfile.js nor bower.json file.

Comment: This says it will fix the problem (if it was generated with yo) https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link I referenced in comment above fixed it for me... just had to run

```
npm install chalk
```

in the project directory as a work around until they get one of the grunt dependencies fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Running below commands should fix your errors...

```
$cd /home/tomek/dev/mobilas
$rm -rf node_modules
$npm install
```

Now you should be able to run your app with `$grunt serve` command